# Is 'Mochup' the same as 'Mock-up'?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, technical, errors

I recently came across the word '[mochup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cinecutie/)'.

I am unsure if this is simply a spelling mistake of the term 'mock-up', or if it is a technical neologism with a slightly different meaning. Searching on google for 'mochup definition' returns many results, but none seem to offer an actual definition as far as I can see.

Comment: Every instance that I can seem to find on Google would indicate that it is just a misspelling of ‘mockup’. YouTube videos that use it make it clear that it is to be pronounced as ‘mockup’, which solidifies that.

Comment: Daniel Oertwig is Gernam and Paolo Rampino is Italian. High chance it is not only a misspelling but a wrong usage of the term

Comment: Just a WAG here - could it be a "mash up" or a hybrid of "mash up" and "mock up"?

Comment: @KristinaLopez or maybe it even refers to something knocked together whilst sitting with a laptop in a wifi enabled cafe, sipping a chocolate coffee beverage... Only half joking here, my first thought was the word was suspiciously similar to 'mocha'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a horrible misspelling, (forgiveable for a foreigner who's trying to learn) and it should not be re-used anywhere, as those letters don't even represent the proper syllable sounds to make it sound similar to the intended "mock up".

- mochup  = "mow-chuhp"
- mock up = "mawk uhp"

Comment: But "mocha" (as in coffee) is pronounced with a short /o/ and /k/. It's not pronounced "mow-tcha" and could well form the basis for the misspelling of mockup.

Comment: Probably a BrE vs AmE thing, but "mocha" is "mow-kuh" where I come from.  (OELD says BrE is "Maw-kuh".)

Comment: Our language has never been strictly formalized.  The common pronounciation of "mocha" given this spelling is an inconsistancy that would probably change if we ever write rules for our language that eliminate these discrepancies==>"mohka".  We'd probably have to change our letters to the International Phoenetic Alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

I (Daniel Oertwig) want to clarify that this is really nothing but a misspelling. Although I am not the one who wrote it, I can assure you that it's not some technical terminology.

(I came across this searching for my name on google)